# Multiple connection database with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 different server databases, then I want to create a connection function so that I can retrieve data from different databases with join tables.
previously I had made the function as below, only those connected to the local database...

```
<?php
//Constants to connect with the database local
define('DB_USERNAME_LOCAL', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL', '');
define('DB_HOST_LOCAL', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME_LOCAL', 'db_attendance');

//Constants to connect with the database server
define('DB_USERNAME_SERVER', '******');
define('DB_PASSWORD_SERVER', '******');
define('DB_HOST_SERVER', '*********');
define('DB_NAME_SERVER', 'rlempl');

class DbConnect
{
    //Variable to store database link
    private $con;
    //This method will connect to the database
    function connect()
    {
        //connecting to mysql database
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST_LOCAL, DB_USERNAME_LOCAL, DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL, DB_NAME_LOCAL);
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST_SERVER, DB_USERNAME_SERVER, DB_PASSWORD_SERVER, DB_NAME_SERVER);

        //Checking if any error occured while connecting
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        //finally returning the connection link
        return $this->con;
    }
}


// this is function for query
<?php

class DbOperation
{
    private $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

// this query join 2 table with diferent database
   public function dataExist($pin, $date){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT b.rldate FROM tams_fingerid a JOIN tams_attlog b ON b.rlcode=a.rlcode WHERE a.fingerid='$pin' AND b.rldate='$date'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }
```

Comment: `$this->con` for local will be overwritten every time. How it would decide which database to connect. Pass some identifier to decide to `connect()`.

Comment: So, what should I do ?
replace it with a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do the changes as follows ? Here I am using two local variables. $con_db1 is for one database and $con_db2 is for another database.

I have changed the code with the execution query

```
    <?php
//Constants to connect with the database local
define('DB_USERNAME_LOCAL', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL', '');
define('DB_HOST_LOCAL', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME_LOCAL', 'db_attendance');

//Constants to connect with the database server
define('DB_USERNAME_SERVER', '******');
define('DB_PASSWORD_SERVER', '******');
define('DB_HOST_SERVER', '*********');
define('DB_NAME_SERVER', 'rlempl');

class DbConnect
{
    //Variable to store database link
    private $con_db1;
    private $con_db2;
    //This method will connect to the database
    function connect()
    {
        //connecting to mysql database
        $this->con_db1 = new mysqli(DB_HOST_LOCAL, DB_USERNAME_LOCAL, DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL, DB_NAME_LOCAL);
        $this->con_db2 = new mysqli(DB_HOST_SERVER, DB_USERNAME_SERVER, DB_PASSWORD_SERVER, DB_NAME_SERVER);

        //Checking if any error occured while connecting
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        //finally returning the connection link
        return ['db1'=>$this->con_db1,'db2'=>$this->con_db2];
    }
}
?>


// this is function for query
<?php

class DbOperation
{
    private $db1;
    private $db2;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $connections = $db->connect();
        $this->db1 = $connections['db1'];
    }

// this query join 2 table with diferent database
    public function dataExist($pin, $date)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db1->prepare("SELECT b.rldate FROM tams_fingerid a JOIN tams_attlog b ON b.rlcode=a.rlcode WHERE a.fingerid='$pin' AND b.rldate='$date'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->con` not defined. Should be `con_db1` or `con_db2` depending on what OP wants.

Comment: I have done some changes. It returns an array of connection.

Comment: I have updated the question, where I have included the execution query

Comment: but I found an error after changing as you said earlier, this error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare () on array

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you try with that and see ?

Comment: its work... thats great...
but, what if the query joins a table with a different database ?

Comment: in the statemet, table a from database 1 and table b from database 2...

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly by using queries. However, You can execute the queries separately on each database to get the data and merge them in your PHP function.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could accept the answer :)